# How to validate dateTime input in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, rest, validation, datetime, marklogic

In MarkLogic REST services written in **JavaScript**, I need to validate the dateTime value in the format "2019-12-01T19:54:25.000265Z" or "2019-12-01T19:54:25" so as to be able to use `xs.dateTime()` in further part of my code for processing data.

The input comes in like a String and I need to validate that it is in the right format and has a valid value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`xdmp.castableAs`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.castableAs):

```
xdmp.castableAs(
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "dateTime",
    "2019-12-01T19:54:25")
```

HTH!

Comment: This worked. However, alternatively I already used  if (xs.dateTime(dateTime))  within a try/catch block & that worked too.

Comment: yes, that works too, but catching exceptions is usually relatively slow.